# How can I open a url for both Angular and Nativescript from one component codebase?

Tags: angular, nativescript, nativescript-angular, angular-module, openurl

I am building a NativeScript-Angular app which displays a link than needs to open in a new browser on both the web and mobile.

For Angular, I can use window.open("http://example.com", "_blank"); - which does not work for NativeScript.

For NativeScript I can use utilityModule.openUrl(http://example.com); where var utilityModule = require("utils/utils"); - but this does not work with Angular (and it can't resolve and tns modules).

Is there any way I can use a single method in the my component to launch the default browser on a mobile and also open a new tab on a web browser?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define a Service and have two implementations of it in your code you import "service"

- service.ts: this will have the WEB version on how to open the link.
- service.tns.ts: this will have the nativescript version on how to open the link.

Comment: Thanks Jose. Haven't given it a go yet but sounds like exactly what's needed.

Comment: Hi Jose, I haven't yet marked this as the answer as it seems like the .tns version of my service is not being picked up. Should this happen automatically? Or do I need to ad something else to a configuration file. The tsconfig.tns.ts already has entry        "paths": {
      "@src/*": [
        "src/*.tns.ts",
        "src/*.ts"
      ]
    }

Comment: The error I am getting is System.err: Error: Unexpected value '[object Object]' imported by the module 'AppModule'

Comment: Issue was obviously user error :-) I had to remove all references to utils/utils and will start that over